# SQLjob overview in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I want to query a number of servers to get the status of the sql jobs. It all works fine for one server but i get this error: New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Server" and the argument count: "2" when I have more than one server in the .txt file.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")
    $sqlServerName = Get-Content 'C:\temp\sqlservers.txt'
    $sqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($sqlServerName)


    [Array]$Collection = foreach($job in $sqlServer.JobServer.Jobs)
    {
        $job | select Name, OriginatingServer, OwnerLoginName, IsEnabled, LastRunDate, LastRunOutcome, DateCReated, DateLastModified,NextRunDate
        }

    $Collection | Export-CSV "C:\temp\sqljobs.csv" –noType -Encoding:UTF8
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "Cannot find an overload" means that what you put inside the parenthesis of a method doesn't work. So in this case, `New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server()` can't take two arguments. So loop over the server names and pass one server name at a time:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")
$sqlServerNames = Get-Content 'C:\temp\sqlservers.txt'
[Array]$Collection = foreach ($sqlServerName in $sqlServerNames) {
    $sqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($sqlServerName)

    foreach ($job in $sqlServer.JobServer.Jobs) {
        $job | Select-Object Name, OriginatingServer, OwnerLoginName, IsEnabled, LastRunDate, LastRunOutcome, DateCReated, DateLastModified, NextRunDate
    }
}
$Collection | Export-CSV "C:\temp\sqljobs.csv" –noType -Encoding:UTF8
```